# Create Relationship when Adding Item with Graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo, apollo-client, graphcool

In my apollo project, when a user creates a project it should automatically create the first folder associated with it.

My schema is something like:

```
type Project implements Node {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  name: String!
  folders: [Folders!]! @relation(name: "ProjectFolders")
}

type Folder implements Node {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  name: String!
  project: Project @relation(name: "ProjectFolders")
}
```

So the idea is when a user creates a project it will also create an initial folder, the user can add more folders later. Naïvely, I want to do something like:

```
mutation CreateProjectMutation($name: String!) {
  createProject(name: $name) {
    id
    name
  }

  createFolder(name: $name, $projectId: ?PROJECT_ID?) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [nested create mutation](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/relay-api/nested-create-mutations-ma6eijae7a/) in this case, by either starting with `createProject`:

```
mutation CreateProjectMutation($name: String!) {
  createProject(
    name: $name
    folders: [{
      name: $name
    }]
  ) {
    id
    name
    folders {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

or `createFolder`:

```
mutation CreateFolderMutation($name: String!) {
  createFolder(
    name: $name
    project: {
      name: $name
    }
  ) {
    id
    name
    project {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the parameter is called `folders` and `project`, respectively.